# SCSS dropdown hover menu

Tags: html, css, sass, hover

I'm working on a pure SCSS dropdown menu. The approach I'm trying is to show the child of the hovered parent on hovered. I'm using SASS. See my Markup below. I have commented above the important piece:

**HTML:**

```
<nav class="main-navigation">
    <ul>
      <li class="item"><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li class="subitem">
          <ul>
            <li>subitem</li>
            <li>subitem</li>
            <li>subitem</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      <li class="item"><a href="#">PLot Overview</a></li>
        <li class="subitem">
          <ul>
            <li>subitem</li>
            <li>subitem</li>
            <li>subitem</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      <li class="item"><a href="#">subitem</a></li>
      <li class="item"><a href="#">subitem</a></li>
      <li class="item"><a href="#">subitem</a></li>
      <li class="item"><a href="#">subitem</a></li>
      <li class="item"><a href="#">subitem</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**SCSS:**

```
.main-navigation {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  ul {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 18px;
    .item {
      display: inline;
      padding-right: 43px;
      font-size: 13px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      // this is where the subitem is supposed to show on hover
      &:hover .subitem {
        display: block;
      }
    }
  }
}

.subitem {
   display: none;
}
```

The block of code that I'm doing (or lt least trying) to utilize to show the child of each hover is this:

```
&:hover .subitem {
   display: block;
}
```

But I don't understand why it doesn't work. It compiles to this:

```
.main-navigation ul .item:hover .subitem {
   display: block;
}
```

Which is essentially the same as [the W3Schools example](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dropdown_text) which is this:

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

Which in both w3 and my implementation, are children of the parent selector and how as far as I know show child elements on hover.

Here is my jsfiddle for demonstration: https://jsfiddle.net/o2fbvqe0/1/

As I understand it, i should be able to show a child element with `:hover` in CSS but it's not working in this example. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The approach I'm trying is to show the child of the hovered parent

OK, but look at your markup:

> ```
>  <li class="item"><a href="#">item</a></li>
>  <li class="subitem">
> ```

Your subitems are not children (or any other kind of descendants) of your items. They are **siblings**.

Correct markup would be:

```css
ul ul { display: none }
ul li:hover ul { display: block; }
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="item">
      Section name
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li>Menu item</li>
        <li>Menu item</li>
        <li>Menu item</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      Section name
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li>Menu item</li>
        <li>Menu item</li>
        <li>Menu item</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

---

**Danger**: This approach has serious accessibility problems. It is impossible to trigger submenus without using a pointing device (this excludes anyone who is dependant on a non-pointing based form of navigation, including most screen reader users) and requires a steady hand to track the pointer down the submenu without siding out of the edge (this excludes people with mobility/dexterity issues such as many people who suffer from arthritis).

Reconsider this approach and look for a system which is:

- Click based
- Has real links that go to useful places at the top level of the menu
- Uses naturally interactive elements to trigger the submenus (e.g. links or buttons but not list items)

You'll almost certainly want to use JavaScript which makes this much easier than trying to have CSS to meet those requirements.

Comment: Good point about accesibility...it was the indentation that threw me off.

Comment: But wait...isn't your markup invalid? I thought you couldn't have `<ul>` in an `<li>` - no? I'll see if I can find a link

Comment: @kawnah — No. `<ul>` inside `<li>` is fine and has been since HTML had those elements.